# How to create passwordfile with env variables

Tags: bash, openssl

In my Programm how can i Iterate trough ENV in bash

```
if [ ! -z $USER_1 ]
then
  echo "$USER_1":$(openssl passwd -apr1 $PASS_1) > ./passwords
fi
if [ ! -z $USER_2 ]
then
  echo "$USER_2":$(openssl passwd -apr1 $PASS_2) > ./passwords
fi
if [ ! -z $USER_3 ]
then
  echo "$USER_3":$(openssl passwd -apr1 $PASS_3) > ./passwords
fi
if [ ! -z $USER_4 ]
then
  echo "$USER_4":$(openssl passwd -apr1 $PASS_4) > ./passwords
fi
if [ ! -z $USER_5 ]
then
  echo "$USER_5":$(openssl passwd -apr1 $PASS_5) > ./passwords
fi
```

And so on how can i do it with N "User" when i don't know N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT April 14**: my first version was incomplete, here is a fix.

Create a loop to loop through your users:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER_1=u1
USER_2=u2

N=5
for (( counter=1; counter<=N; counter++ ))
do
    username=USER_${counter}
    password=PASS_${counter}
    echo "DEBUG: $username"
    echo "DEBUG: ${!username}"
    if [[ -n ${!username} ]]
    then
        #echo "$username:$(openssl passwd -apr1 "$password")"> ./passwords
        echo "DEBUG: USER_${counter} inside if"
    fi
    echo "========="
done
```

- To use on your setup, comment out the debug statements and uncomment your openssl line.
- My first version did not properly user the variable `counter` inside the other `USER_?` variable.
- With this particular script, `USER_1` and `USER_2` will trigger the `if` since `USER_3` and more are not set.

Comment: The problem is i dont know if the varables exist so i need to check if USER_N exists and if it's true write to the password file

Comment: `-n` does exactly that.  It is equivalent to `! -z`.  See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2236

Comment: Hi it ist smaller but the Problem is i only want to create the users if the var USER_N is set ist you make username=USER_$N and then check if $username is defined it always is true

Comment: Fixed, thanks for pointing out my mistake!